# Where can I find ready to use Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, 16.04, gnome

So I've been around raspberry for a while and I know that you can download some pre-installed image [here](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi). These are officials. When you burn this img file into a SD Card, you just need to plug it into the raspberry, boot it. And everything start up with some default user and all.

Does anything like it exist for Ubuntu 16.04 AMD64 that I could burn into a USB stick and plug into my MOBO ? I wanna skip normal boot and just get started straight away. I cannot find anything like it. Whatever I do, even with live version I always have to either install Ubuntu or Try Ubuntu.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

When you install Ubuntu, it's installed to fit your hardware. The preinstalled raspi images work because they are tailored for very specific hardware.  They exist because raspi devices use a completely different instruction set (ARM) than most consumer devices (AMD64).

There is not a preinstalled image for each of the billions of possible combinations of desktop and laptop hardware using AMD64 instructions.  This would be an impossible feat, and fruitless, since there's nothing particularly difficult about installing Ubuntu on AMD64 systems.

You're already aware of the "Try Ubuntu" option.  If you want Ubuntu to be installed you will have to install it.

Do you have something preventing you from installing Ubuntu?  If so, you should ask about that problem.

Comment: Wow I wasn't aware about that. I thought that as long as the architecture would be AMD 64 it would work regardless of the other hardware part.

I've seen some distro that can be loaded into a USB stick http://ethosdistro.com/ https://github.com/Cyclenerd/ethereum_nvidia_miner and work directly. How are they doing it ?

Comment: That doesn't appear to be a fully functional linux distribution in that it supports only one task, and even then it's for specific hardware and won't work on all devices.  If you have a problem preventing you from installing the system, ask about that.  This path you've imagined is a non-starter